# Prevent mousedown from stealing focus of current input but allow text selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to prevent a mousedown in a div to steal focus, but allow text selection in this container (e.g. `<div>`)?

```js
/*// Version #1: Focus kept, but text is not selectable
$('div').on('mousedown', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
/**/

// Version #2: Focus kept, text selectable, but focus is missing for a short time (flickering when css is applied to focused state)
$('div').on('mousedown', function(event) {
  window.setTimeout(
    function() {
      $('input').focus();
    }, 1
  );
});
/**/

$('input').focus();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" />
<div>A div container with some text, that should be selectable but not stealing focus of the input field</div>
```

My second version flickers, when just clicking the text (tested in current Chrome). In Firefox the selection always starts at the input field. Is there any better solution?

Comment: and why `window.setTimeout(` ??

Comment: @bipen Without setTimeout the text ist not selectable. Try it in chrome. This solution does not work in firefox.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is right in front of your eyes :)

```js
/*// Version #1: Focus kept, but text is not selectable
$('div').on('mousedown', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
/**/

// Version #2: Focus kept, text selectable, but focus is missing for a short time (flickering when css is applied to focused state)
$('input').on('focusout', function(event) {
 //setTimeout(function(){$('input').focus()}, 1);
});
/**/


//$('div').on('mouseup', function(event) {
//  $('input').focus();
//});

$('html').on('mouseup', function(event) {
  $('input').focus();
});


$('input').focus();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" />
<div>A div container with some text, that should be selectable but not stealing focus of the input field</div>
```

The issue that if your `mouseup` happens outside this `div`, the focus is lost will persist.

Another approach would be to bind the `mouseup` even on the `html`, though this sounds a little excessive IMO, but seems to work.

The problem is that if you want focus to return to the input checkbox, you'll need to use the `focusout` event, shown in the snippet. The other paradigm of "keeping" focus on the input box wouldn't work, because Javascript is synchronous and only one thing can run at a time.

Comment: Well in that case, use the `focusout` event. Updated the snippet

Comment: Holy cow don't use `focusout` the way I used it. It freezes the page completely. But you get the idea. Editing out the problem child in the snippet

Comment: The problem is that if you want focus to return to the input checkbox, you'll need to do this. The other paradigm of `keeping` focus on the input box wouldn't work, because javascript is synchronous and only one thing can run at a time.

Comment: Updated the snippet with a possible solution

Comment: This version does not work, when the focus should be set to another element than the div. Maybe another input, a link or something else.